# Difference between `\@listi` and `\@listI`

Tags: lists, sourcecode

The LaTeX2e sources PDF says I should use `\@listi` to set the list spacings, but I only see a change if I use `\@listI`. How come?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more or less documented in `classes.dtx` (rather than source2e) where it says

```
% \begin{macro}{\@listi}

% \begin{macro}{\@listI}
% |\@listi| defines the values of
% |\leftmargin|, |\parsep|, |\topsep|, |\itemsep|, etc.\ for the
% lists that appear on top-level. Its definition is modified by the
% font-size commands (eg within |\small| the list parameters get
% ``smaller'' values).
%
% For this reason \@listI is defined to hold a saved copy of \@listi
% so that |\normalsize| can switch all parameters back.
```

so `\@listi` is the generic name for settings for first level lists as used by the format's list code.

`\@listI` is a macro used in the default classes to save a "default default" settings to reset `\@listi` when needed.